# Ember.JS When I create a new record, how can it be Sorted

Tags: ember.js

I have a view showing a ticket and it's replies.

The replies are reiceved `ordered_by Created_at DESC`

When I save a new reply here is what I do :

route :

```
model(params) {
return hash({
  ticket: this.store.findRecord(
    'ticket',params.ticket_id,{include: 'replies'}
  ),
  owners: this.get('store').query('adminUser',{filter: 'supporters'}),
  reply: this.store.createRecord('ticket/reply')
})
}
```

And the controller :

```
saveReply(reply){
  reply.set('ticket',this.get('model.ticket'))
  let promise=reply.save()
  promise.then(
    (reply)=>{
      this.set('model.reply',this.store.createRecord('ticket/reply'))
      return reply
    }
  )
  return promise
}
```

The replies are shown from the most recent to the oldest. Instead of having the new reply at the top of the list, it's at the bottom. How can I order the `ticket.replies` ?

EDIT : 
I tried to use a computed property, but the trigger is not working :

```
sortedReplies:computed('model.ticket.replies[]',function(){
  return this.get('model.ticket.replies').sortBy('created_at:desc');
})
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but you're missing a dot in the CP keys. Should be `replies.[]`. Instead of `replies[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using :

```
sortedReplies: computed('model.ticket.replies.@each.created_at',function(){
  return this.get('model.ticket.replies').sortBy('created_at').reverse();
})
```

I am leaving it open in csae someone has a more optimized answer

Comment: You may want to use the [`sort` macro](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.8/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/sort). Reduces the complexity and you could easily make the sort criteria dynamic.